# change character reference to dataframe name

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to change my paste command from class `character` to a class that references the dataframes in my environment.

The dataframes already exist and are named bid1, bid2, bid3, etc...

Running this code:

```
for (i in 1:length(bids)) {
  paste("bid", i, sep= "") <- paste("bid", i, sep= "") %>% filter(.[[5]] > 3)
}
```

Returns this:

```
 Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

So what should I do differently to get it to reference the dataframe of the same name and not see it just as a character element?

Answer (score 0):

We  can use `assign` instead of `<-`

```
for(i in seq_along(bids)) {
     tmp <- get(paste0("bid", i))
     assign(paste0("bid", i), tmp[tmp[[5]] >3,])

  }
```

---

Much better option would be to keep this in a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^bid\\d+$")),  function(x) x[x[[5]] > 3,])
```

Or if we need to update the original objects

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
bids <- c('bid1', 'bid2')
set.seed(24)
bid1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 5 * 10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
bid2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 5 * 10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
```